# Is it reasonable to start using Google Maps for Flash rather than Javascript version?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, google-maps

I am planning to build a web application highly based on Google Maps API. I am considering either using the Javascript version, or the Flash version. I would like to create an interface which will be quite rich. Should I go for JS version of the API or Flash one? Also I do not plan to purchase Flex Builder, so ideally I would like to use some free Flex SDK that supports ActionScript. What would you recommend? Is it more reasonable to use JS or maybe better use the Flash Version. What are the limitations, pros and cons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantages of Flash:

- Fully cross-browser/cross-platform.
  Write once, run everywhere (except
  iPhone & iPad).
- Virtually same syntax
  as Javascript, only with class-based
  OOP, strong data-typing, etc.
- Very fast UI effects (high frame-rate, etc.), much faster than JS/HTML5, way less CPU usage

Disadvantages:

- Steve Jobs hates it.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, I've built apps using both the Flash and the JavaScript version of the Google maps API. I find that there's not too much difference between the actual API itself. However, I find that creating apps with the Flash/Flex version is much easier because you get a real component based environment to build your app. In my opinion this leads to much cleaner code and maintainable applications whereas the JavaScript applications tend to get messy.

I do not know how it is to develop Flex apps without the FlashBuilder but I guess it's doable. In the end it's a good investment.

Answer (score 0):

Go for Flex....

1. Fully cross-browser/cross-platform.
2. You can find a lot of articles and support.
3. Coding wise its strict and neat compared to JavaScript which is loosely typed language.
4. You can find a lot of custom components and third party API's which can bring more rich look and feel as well as high usability.